# Batch: How to remove a network printer //server/printer if V4 driver is installed?

Tags: windows, drivers, network-printer

All Windows client computers use a network printer //server/printer with V4 driver. The current version of the driver on the server side is V3. I want to remove the V4 printer and reinstall the network printer with the driver V3.

How can I detect if the driver version V4 is used and remove the printer? I need to implement this in a bat file but I can run PowerShell commands from the bat file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [document](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/SMBPrinterDriver/W/V4BDL/1.0/EN/contents/dwu-inst-updt_uninst-uninst.html) were you have options to uninstall drivers that were installed by an installer or by specifying an inf file and also as you can see at the screeshot on the same document you can verify the driver version prior to uninstall or I also share this [guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-device-driver-version-windows-10) to verify the version of a driver installed on Windows 10 (this might differ, depending on your OS version)

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to detect if the driver is V3 or V4 but I know that the correct driver is eg. Xerox GPD PCL6 V5.733.11.0. If the driver is anything else, I'll remove and reinstall my network printer.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell -c "Get-Printer -Name "\\%server%\%printerName%" | Select -ExpandProperty "DriverName""') do set "driver=%%i"
if not "%driver%"=="%correctDriver%" (

    powershell -c "get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where{$_.ShareName -eq '%printerShareName%'} | remove-Printer"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /noBREAK >NUL
    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\%server%\%printerShareName%
)
```